# Delphi 7 TIdHttp post a form with variable fields

Tags: delphi, variables, post, field, indy

I need help with a school related question.

This was on last year's test but I lost the answers and it has been a busy year and I don't remember jack since we're not using Delphi anymore.

We have this web form:

```html
<form action="action" id="id" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="var_name_1" value="var_value_1"/>
    <input type="text" name="var_name_2" value="var_value_2"/>

    <input type="text" name="constant_name" value="constant_value" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

`var_name_1`, `var_name_2`, `var_value_1` and `var_value_2` are four different field names and values and they change every time the page is requested, for example they can be like this

```html
<input type="text" name="12345" value="566"/>
<input type="text" name="1222" value="4444abcd"/>
```

Then if you request the page again they will like this

```html
<input type="text" name="666" value="123456789"/>
<input type="text" name="XXXLUKEXXX" value="A is the first letter"/>
```

I'm sure you got it, I just had to clarify some more.

I remember how to Post using Indy components (I think):

```
c := tidhttp.Create(self);
p := tstringlist.Create;

p.Add('var_name_1=var_value_1');
p.Add('var_name_2=var_value_2');
p.Add('constant_name=constant_value');
p.Add('button=submit');

result := c .Post('http://www.test.com',p);

p.Free;
c.Free;
```

But I don't know how to get those random field names and values. Especially that they change. I know how to do this with a `TWebBrowser` but I need the Indy version because we moved to raw sockets.

Comment: why you do not use 'result' ? Where should be an output if the provided variable is not used ? You show us a `<form>` where you handle the input into this form ?

Comment: @moskito-x: None of that info is relevant to this question.

Comment: You could just ask your instructor for another copy of the answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : To use `result` is not relevant ? To post a param like  `var_name_1=var_value_1`  .  and asume the dynamic file (`.php .cgi .jsp javascript`) generates the `<form> ... </ form>` tag dynamically. Then he will get exactly again as the result ` <form> ... var_name_1="var_value_1" ... </form>`. This is not particularly useful. If the requested file is not dynamic he will get what is hardcoded in the .html file . No chance to change values inside the .html file.

Comment: the output is irrelevant, we're doing protocols that's all, tried asking for the answers, the teacher does not care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are asking for, you will have to download the actual HTML itself (such as with `TIdHTTP.Get()`) and parse the webform data from it, just like any web browser has to.  Parsing HTML is outside the scope of Indy itself.  There are 3rd party HTML parsers available for Delphi, or you can parse the HTML manually since you know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Ye ye I thought of that first, parsing is easy but wouldn't Get change the Names and Values as suggested by the question? 
Please tell me I'm wrong because that would be the answer.

Comment: Every time you `Get()` the HTML, it would change, yes.  But the same thing happens when you load the HTML page in a web browser.  It gets the HTML, renders it, then posts the parsed+entered data when submitted.  There is no difference between TIdHTTP and a web browser in this situation.  You have to `Get()` the HTML, parse it, then `Post()` the values to the URL specified in the webform as needed.  Done.

Comment: I identified the problem, I had the answer all along but it's the TidHttp.Post, it is not sending the data, nothing at all. Might have to ask another how to but it's unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: I assure you that `Post()` does send data when used properly. If you are encountering a problem with it, you should post a new question about it.  It likely will get answered.